# mod_rewrite doesnt work if file with same name as argument exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm experiencing some issues with mod_rewrite in htaccess.

Let's for instance say I request example.com/foo/, it works perfectly if I don't have a file starting with "foo.*" in the root directory.

Let's say I have news.php, sitemape.xml, style.css in root, I can't use /news/ or /sitemap/ or /style/ , it will give a 404 like /news.php/ etc.

Here's my rewrite string. It works locally with my Apache 2.2.22 but not at my web-host with the same Apache version.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Post the entire .htaccess content. error is not in the provided line.

Comment: Its all except "RewriteEngine On" on the row before. Does my webhost have any misconfiguration`?

Comment: Then ask your hoster what may cause with behavior. He definitely has some specific configuration.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like [Multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) rearing its ugly head when its not wanted. It may be that your host automatically turns on the `Multiviews` option by default, and mod_negotiation then tries to "guess" what the request is for, and if it's close enough (like with `/news/` and `/news.php`), it will automatically serve it, and disregard whatever mod_rewrite rules you may have.

Try turning off multiviews. You can do this in your htaccess file using the [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) directive (assuming your host has allowed Options):

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Adding the row above gave "Internal Server Error" so I guess that I'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: @user1677709 then you need to ask your host to make sure it's turned off or add an `AllowOverride Options` for you